How to set USB drive auto mount option?
I have a few USB drives connected to my MacBook Air.
However, other than the one formatted as exFAT, all APFS USB drives auto mounted without the "noatime" option.
How can I configure the mounting process to add "noatime" on external APFS drives also?
Edit 1
I checked already Is it possible to add the noatime mount option to /System/Volumes/Data?. That is for internal disk with fix path/name.
I need solution for USB external drive that come and go and with label/name don't know in advance.
Edit 2
The link in Seamus answer gives a partial solution. Everytime after reboot or after plugging in a usb drive, I can run the following command to add the noatime option:
sudo mount -u -o noatime,nodev,nosuid,noowners /Volumes/<USB DRIVE LABEL>

Edit 3
Another partial solution found.
In /etc/fstab, use following line
UUID=<APFS partition UUID> none apfs rw,noatime

MacOS /etc/fstab behave differ than command line mount.
I have to specify noatime,nodev,nosuid,noowners with command line mount.
However, using rw,noatime,nodev,nosuid,noowners in /etc/fstab will prevent the drive from mounting completely.

However, I am wishing for a more automatic solution.

This question is similar to: Is it possible to add the noatime mount option to /System/Volumes/Data?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Try this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/426023/149366

Please see my PS update.

OK - important clarification/update! Have you looked at this answer? It's a bit old & the utility was last updated some time ago, but if you want/need this behavior (noatime) it may be worth a try. You might want to consult Apple's Disk Arbitration Programming Guide.

I'm not sure this is an Answer - at least in the sense that it offers a clear and universal Solution. In any case, it's too long for a Comment, so here goes:
The OP's update/clarification that this question is WRT 'USB external drives' is (or seems to be) significant. Some brief research (esp. this answer) suggests that mounting inserted USB sticks/drives is controlled through something called Disk Arbitration. It also seems that Disk Arbitration has been around for a while.
It's also interesting there's another question in this SE that asks the opposite question: How do I remove "noatime" from a filesystem mount on macOS Monterey? This suggests that Apple has made a fairly recent change; continuing to diddle with settings - and of course never explaining why.
A comment to that Question links to this answer - which is enlightening and definitely worth reading. The OP did not mention which filesystem he's using, but if it's APFS that answer will most likely be part of the overall solution. The other answer is informative as well.
The only "ready-made" solution I could find that might be able to modify the noatime parameter is a forensic program called Disk-Arbitrator. Unfortunately, it appears to have been compiled for Intel Macs back in 2017... It might still work on a current Intel Mac?? If not, and if it's really important to you - perhaps you could re-compile it on a modern machine?

The answer in the link https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/470662/81965 gave a partial solution. The 'mouint -u -o noatime,...' command can be used each time after reboot or after plugin a usb drive. However I am wishing for a more automatic solution. I will update the question.

The issue with Disk Arbitration, though it is in brew,  it is no longer maintained.
